# SQL Subtract two different averages in one single table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data with two columns: `Date` and `Value`. I want to subtract the averages for each month - let's say September and October 2016. I do following:

```
SELECT 'September' AS Month, AVG(Values) AS Average 
FROM myTable
WHERE MONTH(Date) = '09' AND YEAR(Date) = '2016'

SELECT 'October' AS Month, AVG(Values) AS Average 
FROM myTable
WHERE MONTH(Date) = '10' AND YEAR(Date) = '2016'
```

I can't crack the code, so I get my data in one single table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Avg(CASE WHEN MONTH(Date) = 9 and YEAR(Date) = 2016 THEN Values END) as sept_avg,
       Avg(CASE WHEN MONTH(Date) = 10 and YEAR(Date) = 2016 THEN Values END) as oct_avg,
       (Avg(CASE WHEN MONTH(Date) = 10 and YEAR(Date) = 2016 THEN Values END) - 
        Avg(CASE WHEN MONTH(Date) = 9 and YEAR(Date) = 2016 THEN Values END)
       ) as difference
From myTable
     where 
From myTable
Where YEAR(Date) = 2016 and MONTH(Date) IN (9, 10);
```

Note that `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` return numbers, no strings, so the constants you use should not use single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,is it ok for result

```
SELECT Year, Month, AVG(Values)
FROM MyTable
WHERE YEAR(Date) = '2016'
GROUP BY Year, Month
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(Date) as [Month],YEAR(Date) as [Year],
AVG(Values) OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(Date),YEAR(Date)) 
FROM Table

OUTPUT

```
Month Year  Avg
9     2010   60
10    2010   15
```

Now you can write CTE to get the final avg differences as below

```
;with cte as(
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(Date) as [Month],YEAR(Date) as [Year],
AVG(Values) OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(Date),YEAR(Date)) val
FROM Table
)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.val - t2.val FROM cte t1 
              CROSS JOIN cte t2
              WHERE t1.[Month]=9 AND t2.[Month]=10
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it will solve your problem permanently.

```
SELECT
      MONTH([current].Date) as Month, avg([current].[Values]) Avgr, ISNULL(avg([current].[Values]), 0) - avg(next.[Values]) as Diff
FROM        myTable AS [current]
LEFT JOIN   myTable AS [next]
      ON MONTH([next].Date) = (SELECT MIN(MONTH(Date)) FROM myTable WHERE MONTH(Date) > MONTH([current].Date))
GROUP BY MONTH([current].date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Btw - I suggest you don't use reserved names like "values" for your column names.

```
DECLARE @t table(date date, value int)

INSERT @t values('20160901',20),('20161001',10),('20161001',12)

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT value, month(date) m, year(date) year
  FROM @t
  WHERE date >='2016-09-01'
  and date < '2016-11-01'
)
SELECT year, [10]-[9] difference
FROM CTE
PIVOT
(avg(value)
FOR m
in([9],[10])  
)AS p
```

[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/571181/example)